# Should this use the "map" method?

Tags: ruby

Is there a more elegant way to do this? I feel like "`map`" should be in there somewhere:

```
[
    :method_a,
    :method_b,
    :method_c
].each do |method|
    items.each do |item|
        self.send(method, item)
    end
end
```

Comment: is the call order important ? why not simply use `items.each {|i| method_a(i); method_b(i); method_c(i) }` ?

Comment: If you use `map`, you will just be replacing `each` with `map`, so from the perspective of appearance, nothing changes. The difference will be wether or not you get the side effect, as toddsundsted writes.

Comment: A slight simplification will be removing `self.` on line 7.

Comment: @m_x: yes, the call order is important in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whether to use `map` or `each` depends totally on whether or not you want the operation to return a list of the results of the application of the method (the `send`) or not.

Answer (score 3):

BTW, you can use [`product`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Array%3aproduct) method to eliminate nested structures:

```
[
  :method_a,
  :method_b,
  :method_c
].product(items).map{|method, item|
  send(method, item)
}
```